# Opencv on MacOS Xcode can not use imread to read image based on C++

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I am not sure why I cannot read an image by using imread function and the details about my code are as the following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cv::Mat scrImage = cv::imread("/Users⁩/zsk⁩/Downloads⁩/zsk.JPEG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if(scrImage.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "something wrong" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cv::Mat scrGray;
    cv::cvtColor(scrImage, scrGray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    cv::imshow("scrGray", scrGray);
    cv::Mat blurDstImage;
    blur(scrGray, blurDstImage, cv::Size(5, 5), cv::Point(-1, 1));
    cv::imshow("blurDstImage", blurDstImage);
    cv::imwrite("/Users⁩/zsk⁩/Downloads⁩/blurgirl.jpg", blurDstImage);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.3 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /tmp/opencv-20181001-83194-s618mv/opencv-3.4.3/opencv_contrib/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2018-10-01T12:58:23Z
    Host:                        Darwin 18.0.0 x86_64
    CMake:                       3.12.2
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/gmake
    Configuration:               Release

CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3
      requested:                 DETECT
      disabled:                  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX AVX2
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (3 files):          + SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (1 files):            + SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (9 files):            + SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (1 files):      + SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_SKX

C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++11:                       YES
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang++  (ver 10.0.0.10001145)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Winconsistent-missing-override -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Winconsistent-missing-override -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Winconsistent-missing-override -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Winconsistent-missing-override -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):
    Linker flags (Debug):
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:
    3rdparty dependencies:

OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann fuzzy hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python2 python3 python_bindings_generator reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching tracking video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    js text world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv freetype hdf java matlab ovis sfm ts viz
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         YES

GUI: 
    Cocoa:                       YES

Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/libz.dylib (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 1.5.3-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         /usr/local/lib/libpng.dylib (ver 1.6.35)
    TIFF:                        /usr/local/lib/libtiff.dylib (ver 42 / 4.0.9)
    OpenEXR:                     /usr/local/lib/libImath.dylib /usr/local/lib/libIlmImf.dylib /usr/local/lib/libIex.dylib /usr/local/lib/libHalf.dylib /usr/local/lib/libIlmThread.dylib (ver 2.2.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES

Video I/O:
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 58.18.100)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 58.12.100)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 56.14.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 5.1.100)
      avresample:                YES (ver 4.0.0)
    AVFoundation:                YES

Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2018.0 interface 10005)

Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2017.0.3 [2017.0.3]
           at:                   /tmp/opencv-20181001-83194-s618mv/opencv-3.4.3/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_mac
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2017.0.3)
              at:                /tmp/opencv-20181001-83194-s618mv/opencv-3.4.3/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippiw_mac
    Lapack:                      YES (/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework)
    Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.5)
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                NO
    Link libraries:              -framework OpenCL

Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python (ver 2.7.15)
    Libraries:                   /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (ver 2.7.15)
    numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.15.1)
    packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages

Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3 (ver 3.7)
    Libraries:                   /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-darwin/libpython3.7.dylib (ver 3.7.0)
    numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.15.1)
    packages path:               lib/python3.7/site-packages

Python (for build):            /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python

Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/include /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/include
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

Matlab:                        NO

### Install to:                    /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.3

Comment: and what is the error? just empty? does the app have read access to file?

Comment: The error is just empty and I am not sure what is the problem. I try to use g++ in the command line to run my code, but I got the same result.

Comment: maybe your file has not enough permissions?

Comment: Well, you mean I cannot access my zsk.JPEG image file through Xcode, right?

Comment: But I can read that image by using python cv2.

Comment: Wild guess: you don't have a build with JPEG support, or are missing a library.

Comment: Png file cannot be loaded too.

Comment: Please add result of  `std::cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << std::endl;` command to your question

Comment: please check it

Comment: Well, I just have a try. But it seems that it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find that the problem is that Opencv is header only which needs to special compile.